# set font from dialog box pyside python

Tags: fonts, pyside

i am setting a simple text editor and one of its item is the capability of formatting the font. i am using a dialog box to chose the font and giving a default value; i am using QFont to set the default. I would like to set the default to 'consolas' or 'liberation mono'; i found the former to be easier to implement. however when i launch the window, the default font is not 'consolas'.

how shall i set the code for QFont in order to get 'consolas' or 'liberation mono' regular?
this is the code i wrote:

```
def fontChange(self):
        (font, ok) = QFontDialog.getFont(QFont("Consolas", 11), self)
        if ok:
            self.textEdit.setCurrentFont(font)
```

thanks

Comment: Set the font in the `__init__` method of this class.

Comment: Thank you, i did it with:    `def initGUI(self):
            ...
            self.setFont(QFont('Liberation mono', 10))` and it works